# What should I use to create own xbox controller?

Tags: arduino, controller

For a college project I am going to create my own xbox controller. I wanted to know which arduino should I purchase and which software can be used to code the buttons.
Otherwise what could I use to make my own controller?

Comment: You can't post something on here and just expect a whole detailed answer. This is for specific answers to specific questions. I'm sure there's a blog post somewhere on hacking an xbox controller, and if you get really stuck on a specific question then ask away on here, but general questions like that aren't what it's for

Comment: I dont want a detailed answer. I just needed a place to start. Any post about basics, anything at all.

Comment: @VyprNoch As he has said, this is a very broad question, which part are you stuck on? It sounds like you could ask multiple questions here to get to your answer. "I want to make an x-box" controller is like asking, "I want to make a microwave."

Comment: At least the first half of the question is clear enough to answer, in effect the real question is what the requirements are for interfacing to the xbox, and Passerby's answer seems to have identified them.  And the second half would have "the Arduino IDE" as a default answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Xbox controller is a usb composite device, a usb hub with three downstream ports, one for the (not standards-meeting) usb-hid controller, two for the memory cards.

This is why the original xbox controller could be hacked into a computer gamepad by cutting the cable.

[Some information on the Xbox Controller USB descriptors](http://euc.jp/periphs/xbox-controller.ja.html)

If you are going to duplicate it from scratch for an xbox, you need a usb capable microcontroller, to provide a usb 1.1 connection. Good luck.

Comment: So as an answer to the question asked, it would be one of the Arduinos with a reprogrammable USB chip, rather than one with a fixed-function FTDI part.  However, given the possibly apparent need to simulate a hub, it would probably be one with a fairly capable USB chip, so the Leonardo where the USB is done in the main ATMEGA might be the most likely candidate, vs the UNO where modifying the USB firmware is in a more resource-constrained support ATMEGA.  An alternative to consider would be some ARM part with more resources.

Comment: Well, the usb needs to be a programable one, providing usb 1.1 HID like descriptors. The Arduino usb is set up as a usb-cdc (serial port). An attiny with v-usb on it might work. Don't know how important the usb hub chip is (I can't find any info on what chip is used, but it's separate from the controller/hid mcu.) SpritesMods, that genius, replaced the controller with his own atmega88. http://spritesmods.com/?art=xpad

Comment: The leonardo and uno Arduino USB firmwares *are* reprogrammable, and a hardware USB peripheral on an ATMEGA so equipped will be far preferable to trying to squeeze something into an ATTINY which is a much more constrained environment even *before* you try to do USB in software.